# Firefox and chrome css differences : element height is different

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a problem when I design my new website. The height of my elements is different between Chrome and Firefox.

This is the difference

[image: Difference hight between Firefox and Chrome]

this is **html** code

```
<div class="bottombar">
    <ul>
        <li><button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like</button></li>
        <li><button class="comment"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Comment</button></li>
        <li><button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> 0</button></li>
        <li><button class="showcomments"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> 0</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

this is my **css** code

```
.bottombar {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(1, rgba(245,245,245,1)));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(245,245,245,1));
    margin: 2px -5px 0px -5px;
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    display: block; 
    height: 26px;
}
.bottombar ul {}
.bottombar ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
}
.bottombar ul li button {
    border: 0px;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.bottombar ul li button:hover {
    background: #fff;
}
```

and when i add

```
<div class="clear"></div>
.clear { clear: both;}
```

i have this problem

[image: problem]

any help :)

Comment: try to add html,body{line-height:1em;} or just line-height:1;

Comment: creating a fiddle will allow more users to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the browser rendering differences - especially height - can be handled if you use a reset or preferably a normalize CSS file.

Include this CSS file in your HTML and see how this goes.

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers have different default line-heights, and you might need to explicitly write the line height of your element or entire body in pixels in CSS document, and then it will look the same on all browsers.