# Why is a span with same font-size and line height has different rendered heights in chrome and firefox

Tags: css, cross-browser

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/so2n0a8s/1/

On FF, the rendered span height is 18px while on chrome it is 16px.

Why the difference and how to have consistent rendering across browsers.

HTML:

```
<span>Different height span</span>
```

CSS:

```
span {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Edit:
Removing the line-height and box-sizing properties as they don't seem to any difference at all. 
https://jsfiddle.net/so2n0a8s/2/

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082166/firefox-and-chrome-css-differences-element-height-is-different

Comment: It didn't help at all. Can you point to exactly the reason why this is happening. My  css is simple i am giving the font size is pixels (not in relative units) and also giving a specific line height. If you inspect the rendered span in the respective browsers, inspectors show the font-size  and line-height as 15px and 30px respectively in  computed properties. But the rendered span height has a difference of 2px between chrome and firefox. What is causing this difference and how to address this.

Comment: See [Inline elements and line-height](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28363186/1529630), CSS does not define what should happen.

Comment: @Oriol thanks that was helpful. My question is how do i fix this. How can i ensure consistent (pixel perfect) rendering across browsers.